# Renaming multiple files

Tags: python

So i'm trying to rename a list of files with set renames like so:

```
import os
import time
for fileName in os.listdir("."):
    os.rename(fileName, fileName.replace("0001", "00016.5"))
    os.rename(fileName, fileName.replace("0002", "00041"))
    os.rename(fileName, fileName.replace("0003", "00042"))
...
```

but that gives me this error ``` os.rename(fileName, fileName.replace("0002", "00041"))``OSError: [Errno 2] No such file ordirectory ``` (the file is in the directory)

So next i tried

```
import os
import time
for fileName in os.listdir("."):
    os.rename(fileName, fileName.replace("0001", "00016.5"))
for fileName in os.listdir("."):
    os.rename(fileName, fileName.replace("0002", "00041"))
for fileName in os.listdir("."):
    os.rename(fileName, fileName.replace("0003", "00042"))
...
```

But that renames the files very strangely with a lot on extra characters,
what im i doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you trying to rename the file named `0001` to `0016.5`, the file named `0002` to `00041` and so on, or do something else?

Comment: You sequentially renaming SAME file. of course after the first renaming the original file doesn't exist anymore, hence the error.

Comment: asssuming theres more remamings than the ones provided when you get to the `0004` you will have more because `0003` renames to `00042` so the `0004` is included

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that multi-pass renaming works while single pass renaming doesn't means that some of your files contain the `0001` pattern as well as `0002` pattern.

So when doing only one loop, you're renaming files but you're given the old list of files (`listdir` returns a `list`, so it's outdated as soon as you rename a file) => some source files cannot be found.

When doing in multi-pass, you're applying multiple renames on some files.

That could work (and is more compact):

```
for fileName in os.listdir("."):
    for before,after in (("0001", "00016.5"),("0002", "00041"),("0003", "00042")):
        if os.path.exists(fileName):
            newName = fileName.replace(before,after)
            # file hasn't been renamed: rename it (only if different)
            if newName != fileName:
                os.rename(fileName,newName)
```

basically I won't rename a file if it doesn't exist (which means it has been renamed in a previous iteration). So there's only one renaming possible. You just have to prioritize which one.

Answer (score 1):

listdir returns all object's names (files, directories, ...) not a full path. You can construct a full path using: os.path.join().
Your for loop renames, all found objects first to 00016.5, then to 00041 ...

One way to rename the files, could the following:

```
import os
import time

currentDir = os.pathdirname(__file__)
for fileName in os.listdir(currentDir):
    if '0001' in fileName:
        oldPath = os.path.join(currentDir, fileName)
        newPath = os.path.join(currentDir, fileName.replace("0001", "00016.5"))
    elif '0002' in fileName:
        oldPath = os.path.join(currentDir, fileName)
        newPath = os.path.join(currentDir, fileName.replace("0002", "00041"))
    else:
        continue

    os.rename(oldPath, newPath)
```